# Scrapy long time to initialize

Tags: python-3.x, scrapy, web-crawler

Recently when i launch the command "scrapy crawl my_spider" it takes betweem 10 to 15 MIN to start the extensions, enable the middlewares, pipelines, etc. and then starts crawling. Before, this was not happening. Any idea on what could be the causes for this huge low speed?

[screenshot1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Grvl.png)

[screenshot2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EZDVK.png)

Comment: according to the shared logs, it doesn't take anything to initialize, middlewares, pipelines, etc. The problem looks to be doing the first request. You'll have to share your spider code for analysis